# loop return More than Expected

Tags: codeigniter-3

**i have a method which is suppose to count and update sponsorer but true it does count but its returning more that expected and there by making the count inaccurate.**

here is my code

```
public function get_sponsor($downline_username,$user_name){
        if(!isset($downline_username)){
            return;
        }
        //prevent sponsor to count itself
        if ($downline_username == $user_name) {
            return;
        }

        //first update this sponsor before update sponsor sponsor
        $counter    =$this->count_dis_sponsor($downline_username);
        $counter    =$counter+1;
        $data   =array('counter'=>$counter);
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('downline_name',$downline_username);
        $this->db->update('downlines_counter');


        //look for sponsor sponsor
        $this->db->where('downline_username',$downline_username);
        $query  =$this->db->get('downlines');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $sponsor_id     =$row['sponsor_id_fk'];
                echo $sponsor_id.' sponsor';
                if($sponsor_id !='' && isset($sponsor_id)) {
                    //update the counter table
                    $counter = $this->count_dis_sponsor($sponsor_id);
                    $counter = $counter + 1;
                    $data = ['counter' => $counter];
                    $this->db->set($data);
                    $this->db->where('downline_name', $sponsor_id);
                    $this->db->update('downlines_counter');

                    if ($sponsor_id != '' && isset($sponsor_id)) {
                        $this->get_sponsor($sponsor_id,$user_name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so it keep on calling  the sponsor sponsor two times 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the sponsor sponsor code block, maybe you could add a conditional validation just like on the current sponsor :

```
    ...
    //look for sponsor sponsor
    $this->db->where('downline_username',$downline_username);
    $query  =$this->db->get('downlines');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $sponsor_id     =$row['sponsor_id_fk'];
            echo $sponsor_id.' sponsor';
            if($sponsor_id !='' && isset($sponsor_id)) {
                //prevent sponsor sponsor to count itself
                if ($sponsor_id == $user_name) {
                    return;
                }
                //update the counter table
                $counter = $this->count_dis_sponsor($sponsor_id);
                $counter = $counter + 1;
                $data = ['counter' => $counter];
                $this->db->set($data);
                $this->db->where('downline_name', $sponsor_id);
                $this->db->update('downlines_counter');

                // if ($sponsor_id != '' && isset($sponsor_id)) {
                    $this->get_sponsor($sponsor_id,$user_name);
                // }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

And on the inside that block of code, this condition is useless :

```
if ($sponsor_id != '' && isset($sponsor_id)) {
```

because it is on the inside of the exact same conditional logic, and `$sponsor_id` is not changed at all, so it will always be passed anyway.

Comment: wow.... that did it i just have to call it after the get_sponsor() method and every thing worked well... thanks for ur time